# Can I change the size of the Xcode IDE fonts?

Tags: xcode, ide, font-size

I'd like to change the font size of the "Groups & Files" panel of the Xcode IDE.  I know how to change the "Fonts & Colors" in the preferences, but those (seem to) only affect the code window, not the rest of the IDE.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Here's another person wishing for a larger font, and wouldn't mind doing some surgery to achieve this.  I took a look at the XCode .nib files, and didn't see anything obvious.  Has anyone enlarged the font by flipping some bits?

Comment: I never see an IDE can't change font size, Apple was so stupid here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can change the size of the Groups & Files pane by setting the PBXTableFontSize parameter in `~Library/Preferences/com.apple.Xcode.plist`. This needs PBXTableFont to be set first to take effect.

1) Run `defaults write com.apple.Xcode PBXTableFontSize 20` in Terminal, substituting `20` for whatever value you wish to use. 
2) Run `defaults write com.apple.Xcode PBXTableFont Helvetica` in Terminal, substituting `Helvetica` for the font you wish to use. I'm not sure what OS X's default Sans Serif font is, but Helvetica is pretty generic.

Comment: My bad - forgot you need to set PBXTableFont for the change to take effect. Edited answer to work.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have any solution (to date) for Xcode 4. Will let you know if I find something.

Comment: Hey Nate, sorry about the slow reply -- afraid I've not got an update as I'm no longer developing on OS X. It may be worth re-asking this question for Xcode 4 specifically.

Answer (score 4):

I also wanted to do so. It's ridiculously small!

Answer (score 3):

No, I don't believe this is possible - unless you want to start hacking away at XCode's internal structure. I'd file an enhancement request on this.

Comment: Okay.  Thanks.  One the one hand I'm glad that I'm not missing something obvious.  On the other, it's kind of annoying that I can't change that stuff.