# How do I increase font sizes within XCode

Tags: xcode, font-size

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I change the size of the Xcode IDE fonts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950248/can-i-change-the-size-of-the-xcode-ide-fonts)

I have managed to increase the font sizes for the XCode editor window, but haven't found a way to increase font sizes in other areas of the application, such as the Groups & Files side bar and the console window.

Someone suggested using [TinkerTool to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339706/how-to-increase-font-size-in-the-xcode-editor), and I downloaded the tool, but it's not at all clear to me how to use the tool to tweak the fonts for just these two things (and not affect other apps in my system).

If anyone has detailed instructions on how to increase the font size of these two areas of XCode specifically, I would be very grateful!

Thanks

Elisabeth

Answer (score 1):

1. Run `defaults write com.apple.Xcode PBXTableFontSize <font size>` in Terminal, replacing `<font size>` with your preferred font size.
2. Run `defaults write com.apple.Xcode PBXTableFont <font name>` in Terminal, replacing `<font name>` for the font you wish to use. I'm not sure what OS X's default sans serif font is, but Helvetica is pretty generic.

Comment: I believe you mean 20, not 18.

Comment: This doesnt work in Xcode 4. Are there any solutions for Xcode 4?

Answer (score 0):

Within xcode, go to Preferences -> Font & Color, select which items you want to change, then double click on your selection (this is tricky), the font window will show up. Then you can choose which font and size.

Comment: The poster is asking how to change the fonts in the rest of the UI, not the editor.

Comment: Unfortunately this only works for the editor window, not the rest of the UI.